# INSERT query is not letting me post data to database

Tags: php, sql, mysql, insert

I'm trying to implement a `comment.php` script that takes the data from a html textfield and save it to a database in phpMyAdmin. Now the `comment.php`, which is simpler is not adding anything to a comments table.

Here's the code for `comment.php`:

```
<?php 

 session_start();
 require('connect.php');
 $id = $_SESSION['id'];
 $comment = $_POST['comment'];
 $sql = "INSERT INTO `comp595ose`.`comments` 
           (`id`, `comment`) 
         VALUES 
           (NULL, \'This is not working\');";

 $add_comment = mysql_query($sql);

 echo $comment." ";
 echo $id;
?>
```

The `comments` table in phpMyAdmin has only two field, `id(autoincrement)` and `comment`.

Comment: Have you tried calling [`mysql_error`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php) after the query?

Comment: I attempted to add a mysql_error after mysql_query like this $add_comment = mysql_query($add_comment);                         $error = mysql_error($sql);                                                I get the following error                                          Warning: mysql_error() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given in C:\wamp\www\comp595\comment.php on line 10
Hi 2

Comment: Well, yes, you don't pass the *query string* into `mysql_error`. You don't need to pass anything in fact, unless you have multiple connections open to the database at once. Just try `echo mysql_error();`.

Comment: BTW, please use [`mysql_real_escape_string`](http://php.net/mysql_real_escape_string) and learn about [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sql_injection)!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to escape the single quotes.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `comp595ose`.`comments` (`id`, `comment`) VALUES (NULL, 'This is not working');";
```

Try that.. (untested)